# How to edit a cell without using the mouse

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to use the insert shortcut to insert words into and excel cell.
Ex, I have need to do in the cell. But I want to add by June 30th

I have tried cntrl or fn plus insert or insert or just insert alone and nothing happens.

Can anyone please advise on how to use short cut or function keys to insert the cursor in a cell so I can write more in the cell without using my mouse pad?

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter a cell and edit the contents without clicking into the cell. On your computer, unless function-lock is enabled, you may need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> first:

[image]